# Make Tkinter force a "refresh" a text widget in mid-command?

Tags: tkinter

I have a Tkinter root that has a text widget among other items.

When a certain button is pressed, it is configured with command= to run a certain function, of course.

In that function is a for-loop that does 10 *rapid* refreshes of the text widget. I even put a time.sleep(0.1) between each refresh so it would not be too fast.

But, when I run it and press that button to trigger all this, I only see the lag in time while that all happens, and then the final ending result is finally shown in the box.

How can I, inside that rapid loop, force it to refresh the contents of that text widget?

I will paste the full app below. You can see that the first function you see is the one that does the rapid refreshing of the text widget... it's called dummycommand.   THANKS! --eric

```html
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox   
from random import *
import time

def dummycommand():
    for r in range (10):
        textoutput.delete(0.0, END)
        textoutput.insert(END,"|"*randint(1,10))
        time.sleep(0.1)   # THIS IS WHERE I WISH I COULD HAVE IT FORCE A REFRESH OF THE TEXT BOX

def hibox():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("About EricOwn", "Tk-Try-Grid2 was designed and written in 2018 after a long"
                                                 " but not quite as bad research period where"
                                                 " we are not certain of the outcome.")
def roll():
    textoutput.delete(0.0,END)
    textoutput.insert(END,str(randint(1,1000)), 'tag-center')

def quitto():
    root.quit()

root=Tk()
root.wm_title("GridGlob Manager v0.9")

textoutput = Text(root,width=5,height=1,bd=20, background="light blue",font=("Helvetica", 36))
textoutput.tag_configure('tag-center', justify='center')

buttonroll = Button(root,text="Roll the dice", command=roll, activeforeground="blue",
                 activebackground="red",background="green",foreground="orange",padx=50)

buttonchars = Button(root,text="Show the chars", command=dummycommand, activeforeground="orange",
                 activebackground="blue",background="yellow",foreground="light blue",padx=50)

label1 = Label(root,text=" ")

radiobutton_widget1 = Radiobutton(root,text="Radiobutton 1", value=1)
radiobutton_widget2 = Radiobutton(root,text="Radiobutton 2", value=2)

label2 = Label(root,text=" ")


buttonq=Button(text="Info", command=hibox)
buttonr=Button(text="Quit", command=quitto)



# === Just the pulldown menus

menubar = Menu(root)
#=====
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label="About EricOwn", command=hibox)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Quit",command=root.quit, accelerator="Ctrl+Q")
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
#=====
mathmenu = Menu(menubar)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Randomness", command=roll)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Multiplication",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Dancing",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Turtles",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Trip to Ireland",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Sandwich with good sourdough",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Western trot",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_separator()
mathmenu.add_command(label="English",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Social Studies",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Geometry",command=dummycommand)
mathmenu.add_command(label="Guess it!",command=dummycommand)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Math", menu=mathmenu)





# === Now grid them

root.config(menu=menubar)

textoutput.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2)
buttonroll.grid(row=20, column=0)
buttonchars.grid(row=20,column=1)

label1.grid(row=30)

radiobutton_widget1.grid(row=40, column=0, columnspan=2)
radiobutton_widget2.grid(row=50, column=0, columnspan=2)

label2.grid(row=60)

buttonq.grid(row=70, column=0)
buttonr.grid(row=70, column=1)

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time.sleep` is blocking all processes and freezes your GUI. Use `root.after` instead:

```
def dummycommand():
    textoutput.delete(0.0, END)
    textoutput.insert(END, "|" * randint(1, 10))
    root.after(100, dummycommand)
```

In order to limit the number of repeats, you can use key word arguments, with a default value:

```
def dummycommand(n_times=0, default=10):
    n = n_times + 1
    if n <= default:
        textoutput.delete(0.0, END)
        textoutput.insert(END, "|" * randint(1, 10))
        root.after(100, dummycommand, n)
```

Comment: Hmm -- this is great input but it seems to only work halfway.   I changed it to 0.1 of a second, and inserted this line:   root.after(100, dummycommand)     ... However, what happens is:  perhaps the first 5 iterations, it nicely updates the textbox rapidly. But then it freezes after 5 of them, and the entire tkinter/python app freezes on my mac, showing the rainbow ball, and I have to force-quit the app.   Any thoughts on what that is from? :)  Thanks --

Comment: You should replace your function `dummycommand ` with the one from my answer; inserting a line will not worl as long as you still have calls to `time.sleep`

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. I definitely did replace the sleep command with your line. Because I understood that the sleep was causing the problem. ... ug, so, any thoughts on why the freezing happens?

Comment: No, I did not offer 'a line', but a replacement for your entire function. It will not work if you place `root.after` in a loop!

Comment: oooooh!! sorry!! I need to look more closely at these things!   Let me give it a shot, thanks much -- eric

Comment: yes indeed, it works like a charm. I was definitely just glancing at your answer expecting that it would be just a different command to use instead of sleep.  Thanks much!  Now I'll go look up at exactly how the after method is supposed to work.