# Python textbox only updates after loop is complete

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, while-loop, textbox

I have a very long automation that uses a very long WHILE loop.  I would like to be able to have the text in a textbox update as the process is progressing.  However, based on the research I have done, this does not seem to be possible and all of the results "dump" at once when the WHILE loop completes.  This is useless for me.

I would love it if the textbox could update as the SHELL updates as that follows along synchronously with the actual process.

I have made a simple TEST file to see if I can get it to work.  Here is the code for the TEST file:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont  

root=Tk()
myFont = tkFont.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 18, weight = 'bold')
text_cell_bg="cyan"        #TEXT CELL BACKGROUND COLOR
text_cell_fg="black"       #TEXT CELL TEXT COLOR
text_cell_height=2         #TEXT CELL HEIGHT
text_cell_width=30         #TEXT CELL WIDTH
button_bg="blue"           #BUTTON CELL BACKGROUND COLOR
button_fg="white"          #BUTTON CELL TEXT COLOR
button_height=2            #BUTTON CELL HEIGTH
button_width=10            #BUTTON CELL WIDTH

textbox=Text(root)
textbox.insert(END, 'Default Text\n\n')


def count_print ():
    count = 0
    letter = "A"
    while count < 5:
        print("Count = ",count,".  Letter = ",letter,".")
        textbox_value = "Count = {}.  Letter = {}.\n".format(count,letter)
        textbox.insert(1.0, textbox_value)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)

textbox.pack()

button1=tk.Button(root, text='output', command=count_print, font = myFont,
                        height=button_height,
                        width=button_width,
                        bg = button_bg,
                        fg = button_fg)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep` when using `tkinter`. It's better to use a `tkinter` loop. For an example look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738164/11106801)

Comment: If you search this site for `[tkinter] sleep` you'll find over 1000 questions and answers. Have you tried looking through existing questions?

Comment: Why should I avoid using time.sleep with tkinter?  I haven't had any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function using Tkinter from inside the function itself.
Tkinter has a special function for this.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tk_font

root = Tk()
myFont = tk_font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight='bold')
text_cell_bg = "cyan"  # TEXT CELL BACKGROUND COLOR
text_cell_fg = "black"  # TEXT CELL TEXT COLOR
text_cell_height = 2  # TEXT CELL HEIGHT
text_cell_width = 30  # TEXT CELL WIDTH
button_bg = "blue"  # BUTTON CELL BACKGROUND COLOR
button_fg = "white"  # BUTTON CELL TEXT COLOR
button_height = 2  # BUTTON CELL HEIGHT
button_width = 10  # BUTTON CELL WIDTH

textbox = Text(root)
textbox.insert(END, 'Default Text\n\n')


def count_print(n_times=0): # tell your function how many times you have called it
(on the first call this will be 0)
    n = n_times + 1
    letter = "A"
    if n <= 5:
        print("Count = ", n, ".  Letter = ", letter, ".")# you can change the n var on these lines to n_times if you want 0-4 rather than printing 1-5.
        textbox_value = "Count = {}.  Letter = {}.\n".format(n, letter)
        textbox.insert(1.0, textbox_value)
        root.after(1000, count_print, n) # this number replaces and time.sleep  it's set to 1 second right now it also call the count_print function passing n as a variable


textbox.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='output', command=count_print, font=myFont,
                    height=button_height,
                    width=button_width,
                    bg=button_bg,
                    fg=button_fg)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps. also, I don't use Tkinter for my projects and am definitely not very good at using it either so credit for me knowing about root. after goes to this answer,
[Make Tkinter force a "refresh" a text widget in mid-command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893491/make-tkinter-force-a-refresh-a-text-widget-in-mid-command)

Comment: OP's code would print when `n` is `0` but yours wouldn't. Also what is the point in using `n`, and `n_times`. You can remove one of those variables.

Comment: @TheLizzard I see what you're saying and it makes complete sense, that's why I left the comment on the first line of the if statement, if you change the variable's out it will print 0-4 instead of 1-5, also I left the extra variable in to make it easier to change to the other number set or to stay the way it is. I hope this adds some clarification to this.